# Image is not rendering in imageview with Server URL on fragment listview adapter

Tags: android

i want to set image in imageview with URL

i am converting server image to bitmap then putting it on imageview in my listview adapter used in a BaseAdapter

```
try {
            Log.d("AdapterGetView", "threadAvatarURL = " + threadAvatarURL);
            URL url = new URL(Config.HOST_NAME +threadAvatarURL);
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            holder.profileImage.setImageBitmap(image);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //txtUrl.setText("Error: Exception");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier way Use Picasso library:
download the picasso jar file and import on project and use this codes :

```
   ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("Your image Address").memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(img);
```

Comment: not done my image url is http://server.in/UserFiles/Images/X50/PSK_20160609_0830310525618quality_50.jpg

Comment: Picasso.with(this).load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE").into(img);